# Unable to locate element with Python Selenium fin_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium

I have a HTML code like :

```html
<div class="A">
     <div class="B"></div>
     <div class="B">
        <div class="C"></div>
        <div class="C">
            <p class="D"> Element 1 </p>
        <div class="C"></div>
     </div>
</div>
<div class="A">
     <div class="B"></div>
     <div class="B">
        <div class="C"></div>
        <div class="C">
            <p class="D"> Element 2 </p>
        <div class="C"></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

(this is an example, there is more class "A")

I want to extract the text "Element 2" with Python Selenium.
I tried a lot of things but always the same result : No such element: Unable to locate element...

I tried :

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='A:last-child']/p[@class='D']").text
```

same result...

Comment: `driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.A:last-child p.D').text`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this xpath:

`"(//div[@class='A']//p)[last()]"`

The main problem with your xpath, I think, is that the single slash before the `p` element means to only look for direct children of the `div`. You want the double slash to find any descendant.

Comment: @Deïkoz did you try the other answers? If none of them work than it's a different problem entirely, could need a wait method, could be inside an iFrame etc. We don't have enough information to go on.

Comment: If that doesn't work I am fairly confident there is something going on that's not captured in your example... would need more details to diagnose.

Comment: But yes, you should try the other answers in case I'm missing something.

Comment: I'm not sure the last() function is working... Maybe that's the reason ? function() is highlighted.

Comment: Before the <div class A> there is a lot of div, I don't think it's important but...

Comment: This is kind of a guessing game unless you can provide more of the HTML. I think the `last()` function should work, at least based on your example.

Comment: Also, the <div class="A"> it's in reality <div class="class_name1 class_name2" does it have an impact?

Comment: That shouldn't matter for xpath

Comment: elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("(//div[@class='A']//p)[last()]").text

This worked ! thank you !

Comment: Sounds good! would you like to accept the answer?

Comment: You were responsive and attentive, sad we cannot accept several answers but thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
"(//div[@class='A']//p)[2]"
```

This should get the second instance of `Class = "A"` and then the `p` element beneath that

Comment: Thank you! It finally worked !!!!!
I replaced 2 by last()

Answer (score 0):

In this structure Xpath

```
(//div[@class="A"]//p[@class="D"])[2]
```

if this is a second hierarchy or

```
(//div[@class="A"]//p[@class="D"])[last()]
```

if it is a last should work

Comment: Thank you ! the second hierarchy worked without the class D of p ! :)

Comment: Right, there is no need to mention it. The `p` itself is unique there